auth0 redirecting to root route with props code and state in URL when accessing a react protected route
I am having a problem when I want to access a route which is protected by an auth0 AuthenticationGuard. Here is how it works.
If a user is not logged in and wants to access a protected route, the AuthenticationGuard redirects the user to auth0 authentication page. When the authentication is achieved, then the user gets redirected to /user path.
In my case, when the user logged in, he gets redirected to /user path for a couple of milliseconds, then for other milliseconds the user is redirected to root path with these parameters in the URL : /?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D. Finally in the user is redirected to /user route.
The problem is that after a successful login it shows this in the history :

targeted path (/user)
root path with code and value properties (/?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D)
targeted path (/user)

Whereas I shouldn't be redirect to root and go back to the initial targeted path. I should only have in the history the /user route.
After logging in, I should only go /user and that's it.
Does someone have an answer to my issue ?
index.js :
const Auth0ProviderWithRedirectCallback = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
    
    navigate((appState && appState.returnTo) || window.location.pathname);
  };
  return (
    <Auth0Provider onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback} {...props}>
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Auth0ProviderWithRedirectCallback
        domain={domain}
        clientId={clientId}
        authorizationParams={{
          redirect_uri: window.location.origin
        }}
      >
        <App />
      </Auth0ProviderWithRedirectCallback>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

routes :
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} exact/>
    <Route path="/user" element={ <AuthenticationGuard component={ UserAccount }/> }/>
</Routes>

AuthenticationGuard.js :
const AuthenticationGuard = ({component}) => {
    const AuthenticatedComponent = withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
        onRedirecting: () => <PageLoader/>,
    });
    return <AuthenticatedComponent/>;
};


"Does someone have an answer to my issue?" - What is the issue or question? Please [edit] to clarify what any specific issue/question is and what an acceptable/expected outcome/result is to be.

I tried to be clearer, forgive me for that

In onRedirectCallback have you tried a redirect instead of a push action, e.g. navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname, { replace: true });? This likely won't fix the first "/user" entry since it also appears to be a PUSH from that route to the auth0 "/?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D" navigation back to your app, but the replace at this point would remove "/?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D" from the history stack. Do you have any control over how your app navigates to authenticate users?

Actually it did fix my problem. Thank you very much ! I will edit my post about it

If I understand your question well enough it seems like you have an implementation that adds too many entries into the history stack.
In onRedirectCallback you could issue a redirect (e.g. REPLACE) instead of a push (e.g. PUSH) action:
const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {    
  navigate(
    appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname,
    { replace: true } // <-- Redirect instead of push
  );
};

This will update, e.g. replace, the current "/?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D" entry in the history stack to "/user" where you want the user to redirect to.



Current (PUSH)
Using REPLACE




["/user", "/?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D", "/user"]
["/user", "/user"]



This likely won't fix the first "/user" entry since it also appears to be a PUSH from that route to the auth0 "/?code=[value]&state=[value]%3D%3D" path unless you also have control over how your app navigates to authenticate users, but if possible you should also use a REPLACE action there if you can to maintain as clean as possible a browser history stack.

Ah yes you are right. I'am sorry I'm just starting auth0. I don't get how (or where) I can use a second replace to keep only one "/user" entry. I thought about using the property returnTo in AuthenticationGuard. I am going the goo way ? I tried and it didn't lead to something.

What is actually confusing is that when I want to access /userroute with a <Link> component from react-router-dom, I can go straight to /user route without any loading, any further push or whatever. But when I use the URL it get what is described before.

@L_nnd Using the Link and any navigate method is all handled client-side by React-Router, no request is made to a server. If by "when I use the URL" you mean that you are manually updating the URL in the address bar this will make a request to the server for the page/document at that URL and load the page in the browser. Perhaps when you use the client-side navigations the user is already authenticated and don't need to be redirected, but when you load the page maybe any authentication "state" is lost and needs to be re-established, and thus the user is redirected.

@L_nnd A quick Google search has unfortunately not turned up much indication that there is any way to control how the Auth0Provider navigates to handle any authentication flow. The onRedirectCallback is only for handling navigation afterwards once the user is back into your app.
